# How to send individual email to each AWS IAM user to inform about their old access key using AWS SNS service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-sns

**I have implemented following so far:**
I used AWS system Manager automation, AWS config and AWS SNS service to get list of all aged access key on my email.This is working fine.

**Requirement:**
I have multiple IAM users in AWS account whose access key are not rotated in last 90 days.
Now I want to build some automation in account to send email to each IAM user to inform about  their aged access key.

Kindly guide on this.

Comment: You can't do this with SNS. Have you looked into SES?

Comment: No not yet. I will check connectivity of IAM users and AWS SES. Thank you

Comment: There is no connectivity of IAM users and AWS SES. You would have to pull email addresses out of IAM user profiles. Then you would send individual emails by calling the AWS SES API. My comment was mainly to say that there is no way to send individual emails to people using SNS.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a Lambda to do this, run it daily, and send email to the users.

1. Get a list of users from IAM
2. Loop through the list of users
3. For each access key associated with a user determine its age (today - AccessKey create date)
4. If it's over 90 days do something (in my case I delete them)

Here's a python snippet from my Lambda:

```
import json
import boto3
import datetime
from dateutil.tz import tzutc

users = iam.list_users()['Users']
def list_old_keys(warning_sent, keys_disabled):
    for user in users:
        for  access_key in iam.list_access_keys(UserName = user['UserName'])['AccessKeyMetadata']:
            delta = (today - access_key['CreateDate'].replace(tzinfo=None)).days
            if access_key['Status'] == 'Active':
                if delta >= 90: 
                    <Give a Strong Warning to update key>                        
            else:
                if delta >= 90:
                    <Disable the key because it's Inactive and Old>
                    
    return ()
```

As a side note, depending on your compliance you may want to at least disable the key if it's over 90 days old.  I start warning people at 75 days old that their key is going to be deleted and if it's over 90 days old it's deleted.